# MassTransmit - Distributed Messaging Model - Reliable/Durable - NServiceBus too expensive

Tags: rabbitmq, nservicebus, servicebus, masstransit

I would like to use MassTransmit similar to NServiceBus, every publisher and subscriber has a local queue. However I want to use RabbitMQ.

So do all my desktop clients have to have RabbitMQ installed, I think so, then should I just connect the 50 desktop clients and 2 servers into a cluster?

I know the two servers must be in the same cluster. However 50 client nodes, seems a bi tmuch to put in one cluster.....Or should I shovel them or Federate them to the server cluster exchange?

The desktop machine send messages like: LockOrder, UnLock Order.

The Servers are dealing with backend hl7 messages.

Any help and advice here is much appreciated, this is all on windows machines.

Basically I am leaving NServiceBus behind, as it is now too expensive, they aiming it at large corporations with big budgets, hence Masstransmit.

However I want reliable/durable messaging, hence local queues on ALL publishers and ALL subscribers.

The desktops also use CQS to update their views.

Answer (score 1):

> should I just connect the 50 desktop clients and 2 servers into a cluster?

Yes, you have to connected your clients to the cluster.

> However 50 client nodes, seems a bi tmuch to put in one cluster.

No, (or it depends how big are your servers) 50 clients is a small number

> Or should I shovel them or Federate them to the server cluster exchange?
>   The desktop machine send messages like: LockOrder, UnLock Order.

I think it's better the cluster, because federation and shovel are asynchronous, it means  that your `LockOrder` could be not replicated in time.

> However I want reliable/durable messaging, hence local queues on ALL publishers and ALL subscribers

Withe RMQ you can create a persistent queue and messages, and it is not necessary if the client(s) is connected. It will get the messages when it will connect to the broker.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Gas, much appreciate your response. I like some of the benefits of the Cluster. The integrated Dashboard to see the messaging throughput is awesome. However, there is a disadvantage with the cluster. When I upgrade, I have to bring all nodes down to upgrade the Erlang engine or RMQ software. Where as if it is federated or shovelled, it can work with different versions of RMQ on the bus....Thoughts? Also, i realise I will need to build some powerful scripting to setup the cluster queues for the administration and deployment, but this should be easy enough, make a deployment tool.

Comment: Hi @Romiko, Yes you are right, but with some tips you can avoid to get down all cluster nodes. For example detach one node  at time update it, redirect the connections ... (just a bit complex but not impossible).
Usually the cluster update is an rare operation, I think in your case the cluster should be the better solution. And you are right again the federation and the shovel are more flexible and can run with different brokers and eralng version. The choose depends to your requirements. Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I have a FOSS ESB rpoject called Shuttle, if you would like to give it a spin: https://github.com/Shuttle/shuttle-esb

I haven't used NServiceBus for a while and actually started Shuttle when it went commercial.  The implementation is somewhat different from NServiceBus.  I don't know MassTransit at all, though.  Currently process managers (sagas) have to be hand-rolled in Shuttle whereas MassTransit and NServiceBus have this incorporated.  If I do get around to adding sagas I'll be adding them as a Module that can be plugged into the receiving pipeline.  This way one could have various implementations and choose the flavour you like :)

Back to your issue.  Shuttle has the concept of an optional outbox for queuing technologies like RabbitMQ.  Shuttle does have a RabbitMQ implementation.  I believe the outbox works somewhat like 'shovel' does.  So the outbox would be local and sending messages would first go to the outbox.  It would periodically try to send messages on to the recipients and, after a configurable number of attempts, send the message to an error queue.  It can then be returned to the outbox for further attempts, or even moved directly to the recipient queue once it is up.

Documentation here: http://shuttle.github.io/shuttle-esb/